# Histogram Conditional on subset of data in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, histogram

I am new to R (especially its graphics packages) and am having an issue producing Conditional Histograms.

Given the hypothetical data frame df:

```
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(y=c(1:5),a=c(1,1,2,2,3),b=c(2,3,3,4,5), c=c(3,4,5,6,7)))
```

I would like to create histograms of y conditional on the unique combinations of a, b, and c:

```
groups<-unique(cbind(df$a,df$b,df$c))
```

( I understand histograms using this particular data frame wouldn't make a lot of sense, but for simplicity and brevity it will work)

I certainly could look at the unique values of my conditioning variables and write code for each separate histogram, but I'd like to automate the process into something like this:

```
library(lattice)
for (i in 1:5) {    #for the 5 unique groups
    histogram(~y | a==groups[i,1] & b==groups[i,2] & c==groups[i,3], data=df)
    dev.new()
}
```

This code executes and opens the correct number of graphics windows, but produces no output. 
Additionally, if there is an argument to add to the histogram function which will force the output to display only when the condition is met (instead of displaying both TRUE and FALSE panes), I'd be interested in learning that as well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just moving my comment to an answer. This is really easy in ggplot using `facet_wrap`.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = y)) +
    geom_histogram() + 
    facet_wrap(~ a + b + c)
```

Displaying the graphs in different windows won't be built-in with ggplot. For that, I would probably

```
#create a grouping variable
df$group = paste(df$a, df$b, df$c)

# split the data frame
df.list <- split(df, df$group)

# apply a function to each piece
lapply(df.list, FUN = function(data) print(qplot(data$y)))
```

With the split and lapply method, you could easily define whatever function you want, `hist()`, `histogram()`, etc. With your current data `hist()` just shows you a single rectangle, but with more data it would look right.

Comment: Thank you. I had looked at the ggplot2 package a bit but am very unfamiliar with it. Is there a way to display the histograms in separate windows using this approach?

Comment: If you had forced the facets to be 1 x 1  and were doing this in a multipage device, you would have gotten plots on separate pages.